# Catching HttpClient timeouts within an async workflow

Tags: f#, dotnet-httpclient, f#-async

I'm calling `HttpClient` via `Async.AwaitTask`, being called from within an agent (MailboxProcessor). I was wanting to catch errors during the HTTP call so used a `try...with` in the async workflow, but it completely misses catching client-side timeout exceptions which then cause the agent to crash.

Minimal reproduction:

```
#r "System.Net.Http"
open System
open System.Net.Http

let client = new HttpClient()
client.Timeout <- TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.)
async {
    try
        let! content = Async.AwaitTask <| client.GetStringAsync("http://fake-response.appspot.com/?sleep=30")
        return content
    with ex ->
        // Does not catch client-side timeout exception
        return "Caught it!"
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
// Throws System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled
```

I can fix it by making it completely syncronous, but would prefer to keep the whole stack async as might be running a lot of these in parallel:

```
#r "System.Net.Http"
open System
open System.Net.Http

let client = new HttpClient()
client.Timeout <- TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.)
try
    Async.AwaitTask <| client.GetStringAsync("http://fake-response.appspot.com/?sleep=30")
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
with ex ->
    "Caught it!"
// Returns "Caught it!"
```

Is there an effective way of catching the `OperationCanceledException` within an async context?

Comment: This appears to be what ``Async.Catch`` is intended to do, except that it doesn't actually catch the exception - the behavior is the same as the OP's example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because the `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` task will be cancelled, instead of failing with a `TimeoutException`, thus prompting the async mechanism to fire its cancellation continuations, which cannot be handled. A simple way to solve this problem is the following:

```
async {
    try
        let! content = 
            client.GetStringAsync("http://fake-response.appspot.com/?sleep=30")
                  .ContinueWith(fun (t:Task<string>) -> t.Result)
            |> Async.AwaitTask
        return content
    with ex ->
        // Does not catch client-side timeout exception
        return "Caught it!"
}
```

Comment: Great! So, to make sure I understand this correctly - ContinueWith deals with when the task gets cancelled? And the call to `.Result` is only after the task has completed so it's still truly async?

Comment: @danielrbradley Correct. This merely forces cancellation to materialize as an exception which can be handled by async.